# Is it true that if $n$ is a positive multiple of 4, then there exists a primitive pythagorean triple with $n$ as one of the side lengths?

Tags: number-theory

Is it true that if $n$ is a positive multiple of 4, then there exists a primitive pythagorean triple with $n$ as one of the side lengths. Considering the form of primitive pythagorean triple, i.e., $(u^2-v^2, 2uv, u^2+v^2)$ I think the answer is yes. Any hint on a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=$ any even number and $v=1$.  $u^2+1$ and $u^2-1$ are both odd and cannot have a common factor, since the difference $=2$.  Therefore $(a=2u,b=u^2-1,c=u^2+1)$ is primitive, while $a$ is a multiple of $4$..

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ If $2uv$ is not divisible by $4$, then $u$ and $v$ are both odd $\implies u-v, u+v$ are both even.

Edit: As pointed out by herb in the comment, this does not address the question of primitive. We use the fact that a triple of integers $(a,b,c)$ is a *primitive Pythagorean triplet* $\iff$ it can be written in the form $(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2) \ \text{or} \ (2mn,m^2-n^2,m^2+n^2)$ where $m>n$ are relatively prime positive integers and of different parity.

In that [general representation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Pythagorean_triple), either $m$ or $n$ is even, so $2mn$ (always in the triple) is divisible by $4$.

Comment: Question of primitive not addressed.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thank you for pointing it out, I have added an edit.